# Combining conditions into single IF

Tags: angularjs

My current code has the following conditional check.

```
if(
    angular.equals({},obj1) &&
    angular.equals({},obj2) &&
    angular.equals({},obj3) &&
    angular.equals({},obj4)
){
    return true;
}else {
    return false;
}
```

Instead of writing these 4 conditions for 4 objects, is there any shortcut for this option which will reduce the verbos? because in this way, if one more object `obj5` introduced, then i need to add one more line.

Comment: What is the purpose of comparing? Just check if objects are initialized, or trully check if those objects are equal to empty object?

Comment: If you're fetching content for those objects and need to wait until they all arrive then use `$q.all()` to wait on completion of the relevant promises.

Answer (score 0):

Put the objects into an array - and run a `.every` check on the array:

```
function isEmptyObjs(arrayOfObjs) {
    //If every element in the array is an empty object, returns true
    return arrayOfObjs.every(function(obj) { 
        return angular.equals({}, obj); 
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var areObjectsEmpty = isEmptyObjs([{}, {x: 1}, {}]); //returns false
var areObjectsEmpty2 = isEmptyObjs([{}, {}, {}]); //returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option would be just use `extend`.  It's a little more readable, but (imho) the intent of the code is obscured a little bit:

```
if(angular.equals({},angular.extend({},obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4)) { return true; }
```

Still ... it's simpler code, right?  extend will merrily go about adding properties to {} from all those objects and then return a not equal.  I would say that this would run slower, but you are using && -- so you're doing the same type of heavy lift in your && version of the code.